# Function argument is 'Null or Undefined' when it is supplied

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes two arguments, but the second one is undefined for whatever reason. I can't seem to figure out why.

```
function foo(sometext, i) {
    alert(sometext);
    alert(i);
}

function bar() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        foo("text", i);
    }
}
```

When I run this on JSFiddle, it seems to work. When I run the similar code on my local server, I get errors saying i is undefined in foo(). I don't know why, since I am passing a value in for it. I am using a WAS8.0 server, and IE9.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ct58P/4/)

EDIT: Adding the real code.

```
function showResult(data) {
        $('#searchResults').empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#searchResults').append(htmlifyResultsRow(data[i]), i).trigger('create');
        }
 }

function htmlifyResultsRow(dataRow, i) {
    alert(i);
    //Undefined already. I call i.toString() in places, which is where the error shows it self
}
```

The showResults() function is called by some other code.

Comment: Nothing happens in your JSFiddle because you don't call `bar`. *Edit:* Well now your fiddle calls it and it works.

Comment: [If you add a call to the "bar" function it works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/KChkE/)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a call. It's updated. The real issue is still there.

Comment: Is this the actual code involved? If not, then it's not useful as an example of the problem you're having, because it works.

Comment: No you dont pass a value to argument i.

Comment: I can post the real code. It's really no different though. Which is why I'm confused.

Comment: sure you coppied it properly, it sounds like on your local version you missed out a } after "foo", although it is there on the jsfiddle version. Also, what browser are you using

Comment: @SamDenton OP has already pointed out that IE9 is being used.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle with your exact non-working code... otherwise our advises are useless...

Comment: Yea, sorry, on phone so the last line got cut out with out me realising

Comment: I can't provide a jsfiddle with the exact code, as it gets data from other places.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Can you not just replace those data calls with dummy data?

Comment: Also, why all the downvotes? I provided everything relevant and described my problem.

Comment: @ajp15243 I could, but the data is irrelevant. The error shows itself before the data is even touched.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Well, I think lftah and I have spotted your problem simply from your posted code :)

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference but you missed out a perenthisese (not sure on spelling) after(data[i]), i think it needs to be (data[i])),

Comment: The downvotes are because you describe a problem and then show code *without* the problem, this is even worse than not providing any code at all

Comment: Here on stack overflow, I interpret questions literately word for word, so I can't assume that you knew you had to call `bar()` in order to see anything happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at this expression:

```
$('#searchResults').append(htmlifyResultsRow(data[i]), i)
```

You are passing `i` to `.append()`, not to `htmlifyResultsRow()`. This is why `i` is `undefined` in your `htmlifyResultsRow` function, because it is never passed a value for `i` in the first place.

What you're probably looking to do is:

```
$('#searchResults').append(htmlifyResultsRow(data[i], i))
```

Comment: Oh god, I don't know how I managed to miss that. Thanks! Tunnel vision I guess.

Comment: It happens to the best of us

Answer (score 1):

this is the problem:

```
 $('#searchResults').append(htmlifyResultsRow(data[i]), i)
```

it should be:

```
  $('#searchResults').append(htmlifyResultsRow(data[i], i))
```